# Is this a scratch or a smudge on the Sony A7iii sensor?

Tags: sensor, sony, cleaning, scratches, sony-a7iii

[image]

I recently bought a Sony A7iii and have been using it daily for the past 2 weeks. I noticed this on my sensor, are these scratches or can they cleaned by a camera sensor cleaning kit?

I have not cleaned or touched the sensor, I've only blown on it to remove dust.

I bought a cleaning kit today but I'm not sure if it's dust or should I be worried that it's scratches?

If so what should I do as they show up in the image?

Comment: A bigger photo might be useful. The data size limit is 2MB, which is plenty if you keep the jpg quality down a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you were blowing at the sensor with "compressed air" can and it's not the best idea:

1. The detachable nozzle (if your can has it) can fly and hit the sensor
2. The "air" which is not really air can create residue on the sensor if it does not fully vaporize before hitting it which is probably what you have there.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell on the attached image. However if the camera was new at the start, it is more probable to be smudge. It could well be condensation from the compressed air if it was a canned air product that has been used.

As there is glass over the sensor, cleaning it is not witchcraft. You can use the cleaning kit and then see if the issue persists.

Before using a wet cleaning kit, make sure to use a rocket blower or any handheld blower to get rid of dust particles or lint (there seems to be a hair or lint on the grey part on the far left of the image) while holding the opening downwards - so that the debris can fall out.

Please keep to the instructions of the wet cleaning kit. Especially do not use excessive cleaning fluid and only use each side of the swab ONCE.

Answer (score 0):

Has it been that way since you got it? Showing up in images from the beginning? If so, I would not do anything and look to the seller for some recourse if possible.

IMO you should look at getting it cleaned professionally to eliminate any possible issue of you making it worse or causing a scratch. But if you have no recourse, and you can't get it cleaned professionally (or just don't want to); then go for it... if it is scratched you're not going to make it worse.